# My ssh-key has been authenticated but fetching from the repository fails

Tags: git, authentication, github, ssh

My ssh-key has been authenticated but fetching from the repository fails.

#### Problem

- `ssh -T ssh://{address}` gives me the following message: 
  `You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.`
- However doing xcodebuild fails to fetch from the remote repository giving me the following error. 
  `Fetching origin`
      `{address}: Permission denied (publickey).`
  `fatal: Could not read from remote repository.`
      `Please make sure you have the correct access rights`
      `and the repository exists.`
      `error: Could not fetch origin`
- I also get this error on Xcode
  [ssh://{address}](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4N1sE.png)

#### What I have done

- I've generated ssh-key and added it to my Github ssh-key.

```
ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "mail address"
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
```

- I've also set my .gitconfig file

```
[url "ssh://{address}/"]
    insteadOf = {address}:
```

---

Would anybody know what's going on?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  You need to ensure the repository url is correct.

Comment: `ssh://{address}`  does not appear correct at all. My local URLs for SSH access look like git@github.com:Charcoal-SE/SmokeDetector.git

Comment: You should be able to cut and paste the correct repo URL from the browser portal for your Git server. Use the "Code" button on GitHub, or the "Clone" button on GitLab, for example.